# .NET Coverage Not Working on Linux (macOS Apple Silicon) -- No code coverage data available. Profiler was not initialized

Tags: .net, unit-testing, code-coverage, mstest

I am trying to use .NET code coverage analysis to check coverage on my unit tests, but I keep getting a warning message when running "dotnet coverage collect -f cobertura dotnet test"

The message says:
No code coverage data available. Profiler was not initialized.

The .xml file is created but it does not have any data. When I run reportgenerator "-reports:./output.cobertura.xml" "-targetdir:./coverage_report", it creates an html file in 0.0 seconds. When I open it, it does not provide any branch data, just a bunch of NA.

I am using .net8.0.

[Here is what the terminal looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ALhr9.png)

[My html file ends up looking like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/81XmJ.png)

[It should look more like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJ9CT.png)

I have had several troubles with .NET on my Mac, but this seems to be the final issue. Is there a way to make sure that the Profiler is initialized so that the .xml file is properly filled with data?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get my report to work! Instead of the command that I was previously running to generate the .xml report, I ran the following:

dotnet test --collect "Code Coverage;Format=cobertura"

That created a filled .xml file that I was able to create a proper .html report from!